# Using Mipmap resource as Button DrawableTop

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.Android app. I have a button containing text and a DrawableTop mipmap image. When I set the default DrawableTop image in the axml, it's working, my image appears where I want it to.

However, what I'm trying to do, is changing programmatically this image inside the button when clicking on it, and revert after another click (using a boolean to check the actual state).

So, I checked on the internet and found the function to replace drawables in the buttons from C# code. I also need to gather the mipmap image I want, but as the button needs Drawable objetcs, I tried several things, and the only one not crashing is this :

```
Drawable topDrawable = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Mipmap.mymipmap);
filterButton.SetCompoundDrawables(null, topDrawable, null, null);
//The parameters being, in order, left, top, right, bottom drawables.
```

When compiling, I can see my button with the default DrawableTop defined in the layout, but when I click, it disappears instead of showing the new image. My guess is that topDrawable is actually equal to null.

So, I'm looking for a way to get a Mipmap resource and use it as a drawable. But maybe I'm wrong and the problem is somewhere else.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution is simpler that I thought. The drawable isn't equal to null, as I checked with a breakpoint. The problem was with the position of the image. When defining the image directly in the layout, there is an automatically defined position for this Drawable. When replacing the drawable programmatically with the above function, we also replace the position. To keep the original position and just replace the image, we need to do so :

```
Drawable topDrawable = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Mipmap.mymipmap);
filterButton.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, topDrawable, null, null);
```

The name of the function says it all.